# Frames with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, frames

How can I manipulate using JavaScript (JQuery) a site, not in my server, that I loaded in a frame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't. The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents it.

> The same origin policy prevents a document or script loaded from one origin from getting or setting properties of a document from another origin. This policy dates all the way back to Netscape Navigator 2.0.

the only conceivable workaround is to fetch the page through a proxy on your own web server, and do the JavaScript operations on that. This, though, will destroy any relative links on the page, and is therefore usually not a workable approach without a *lot* of work (fixing relative links, etc.)